# Commerce Custom Shipping Methods via Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, php, classes

I'm looking to add additional shipping methods through a plugin, using the documentation here: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/shipping-methods

I'm a little bit lost about how to hook things up, according to the docs I'm supposed to do:

```
public function commerce_registerShippingMethods()
{
    return [new CustomShipper_CourierDeliveryMethod()];
}
```

The docs don't really cover where and how to do this, other than to include it in the base plugin file. That part I can follow. Could someone help me understand what file to create, the basics of what it should include and how to connect it (referring to **new CustomShipper_CourierDeliveryMethod()**)?

This is new to me for Craft Plugin development - I'm used to connecting to files using something like:

```
return [craft()->pluginHandle_serviceName->function_name()];
```

Which obviously is very differently than the above. Any help would be HUGELY appreciated.. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so what you're doing is returning a new instance of a shipping method class - this class must meet the Shipping Method interface - documented here: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/shipping-methods#shipping-method-interface

That is, you must implement each of those functions as defined by the interface in your shipping method class.

You'd define this class in a file of it's own named after the class, and in your base plugin file you `require` this class definition to bring it in to scope.

The same goes for your shipping rules - you again create a class that meets the interface and then `require` that in your main plugin file (or wherever you need to access the rule).

Comment: Am I supposed to extend or implements my custom shipping method class to a specific class? I run into this error: "Argument 2 passed to Craft\Commerce_ShippingMethodsService::getMatchingShippingRule() must implement interface Commerce\Interfaces\ShippingMethod, instance of Craft\MyShippingMethod given"

Comment: I figured it out. The shipping method class needed to 'implements \Commerce\Interfaces\ShippingMethod '. Thanks for the help in figuring out how to hook this all up!

Comment: Good stuff, glad you're off an running.  The hardest part is the structure - once you have that the actual calculator is usually relatively simple ( - and sorry I am in Aus so hard to respond promptly!)